# Cypress failed to start on MacOS

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

When I try to use `cypress open` or `cypress run`, I get the following error:

```sh
 ✖  Verifying Cypress can run /*/*/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress
   → Cypress Version: 3.1.5
Cypress failed to start.

This is usually caused by a missing library or dependency.

The error below should indicate which dependency is missing.

https://on.cypress.io/required-dependencies

If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.
----------

Command failed: /*/*/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/Cypress --smoke-test --ping=984
----------

Platform: darwin (17.6.0)
Cypress Version: 3.1.5
```

There are no dependencies listed in the error, and I'm not using docker. What should I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that worked for me was unsetting the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable:

on MacOS

```sh
unset NODE_OPTIONS
cypress open
```

on Windows

```sh
set NODE_OPTIONS=
cypress open
```

if that fails, try the following as suggested by a [user on Github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1866#issuecomment-398798612):

on MacOS:

- clear `/Users/[username]/Library/Caches/Cypress`
- run `npm i cypress -g`
- run `cypress open`
- close terminal
- return back to your node.js project and run the tests

on Windows:

- clear `C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache`)
- start a command prompt as administrator
- run `npm i cypress -g`
- run `cypress open`
- close command prompt
- return back to your node.js project and run the tests

Answer (score 8):

Simply try `./node_modules/.bin/cypress install` if you're using Cypress for the first time.

Comment: nice thanks! going crazy trying to figure something out that should be so simple by uninstalling and installing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue exists with some of the Cypress versions released recently. Try a  bit of older stable version like 12.0.0. It should work.